# how to configure DefaultShutdownStrategy in application.xml for camel route graceful shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

We are using Camel on Spring Boot, and we have below application.yml properties file to configure some camel settings.

I would like to shutdown my application and camel routes gracefully, so I am tying use DefaultShutdownStrategy, however I am no idea whats the property that I need to use in my application.yml to enable that?

I could not find anywhere online as well, Can anyone shed some light on this please. or how would you suggest to implement gracefull shutdown.

```
# Camel configuration:
camel:
  component:
    servlet:
      # With multiple camel servlets running within the same process you need to set the servlet name.
      # The servlet name is named after the port to ensure uniqueness without having to bring in a new parameter.
      servlet-name: camelServlet${SERVER_PORT:9000}

  springboot:
    name: pilot-manager-service
    main-run-controller: true
    routes-include-pattern: classpath:routes/**/*.xml,classpath:route-templates/*.xml
```

Comment: Any veterans in apache camel ? can you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding graceful shutdown with the `DefaultShutdownStrategy` is enabled by default in Camel.

Below are the defaults for 3.20.x from the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_sb_option_camel_springboot_shutdown-log-inflight-exchanges-on-timeout) for application.yml.

```yaml
camel:
  springboot:
    shutdown-log-inflight-exchanges-on-timeout: true
    shutdown-now-on-timeout: true
    shutdown-routes-in-reverse-order: true
    shutdown-suppress-logging-on-timeout: false
    shutdown-timeout: 300
```

Notet that during unit tests camel seems to ingore at least the shutdown-timeout value and use 10 seconds instead.

You could also do [custom camel context configuration](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_custom_camel_context_configuration) where you can set the camel context shutdown strategy to new instance of `DefaultShutdownStrategy` which you can configure using your own property-placeholders. Do note however that `@PropertySource` annotation might require some extra work with yaml files.